# Spring web mvc portlet in websphere portal

Tags: java, liferay, websphere-portal

Hi everybody i develop a Spring web mvc portlet that's work properly in Liferay portal but when i'm uploading it on websphere a message appears "this portlet is not available". so thinking to solve this issue i have created a new portlet project using :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.ibm.tools.archetype -DartifactId=portletapp-portlet20 -DarchetypeArtifactId=portletapp-portlet20 -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeRepository=http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/ -DarchetypeGroupId=com.ibm.tools.archetype
```

then i change what should be changed. upload portlet to liferay portal and it work but in Websphere portal does not. so what do you suggest me to do. if there is a plugin to create websphere portlet on eclipse or something else  please don't hesitate, i will be so thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to deploy a portlet in WebSphere Portal you need the portlet descriptor (portlet.xml), your class with the @Controller annotation, and all your libraries in the classpath. Check your server log to find the reason for the message "this portlet is not available". WAS v8 have the file in this path: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/logs/WebSphere_Portal/SystemOut.log.